# Why if I start a spring boot app as Java Application from the IDE (Eclipse) it works but when I start it from CMD it get me Whitelabel Error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I have Spring Boot App, if I run the Main Class from the IDE it's all OK and the application works fine.
If I start the generated JAR (by `mvn clean install`) from the command line using `java -jar MyApp-1.0.jar` the application starts, but when I go to `localhost:8080` it gives me Whitelabel Error page:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Aug 02 14:21:00 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp
```

It's like Maven generates a bad JAR file.
Can you help me?

Comment: No need to run `mvn install` when all you need is `mvn package`.

Comment: How did you create the JAR? It surely looks as if the resources that are supposed to go into `WEB-INF` have not been packaged.

Comment: There are two issues here: the file `/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp` may not be bundled in the JAR. Since this error occurred you are seeing the Whitelabel error. To avoid this error create an `404.html` under `src/main/resources/public/error/'.

Comment: I don't want a custom error... i m trying to understand why home.jsp is not bundled in JAR file

Answer (score 0):

Do define the prefix and suffix mapping in your application.properties like below and try

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsps
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp in your application.properties
```

Please check the file below for the mapping https://github.com/hellokoding/springboot-jsp/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Also check the sample springboot project with jsp like below https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp/

Already answered here [Spring boot application displaying white label error when executing jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880927/spring-boot-application-displaying-white-label-error-when-executing-jar-file)

Comment: You say it’s already answered there when said question does not have an approved answer.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1 this article also says the same thing

Comment: @RiccardoPiezzo what is the location of your jsp page

Comment: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp

Comment: spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Comment: An executable jar will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.

What a bummer…

Solution
Just to recap my requirement, I want to serve JSPs out of my classpath so that I can create executable Jar files. Basically, Eliminate the web apps folder.Follow this link step by step it should work https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem recently. I found two alternatives:

1. Run with maven command, mvn spring-boot:run.
2. Use war packaging. war file seems to work without any issues. java -jar MyApp-1.0.war

In both of the above two options, you need not follow the hardcoded file patterns.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. I faced the same issue and I did this to make it work after trying different combinations - strange!

If you are doing everything right and still it doesn't work, make sure you have the @ComponentScan annotation in both Application.java and the controller with the 'basePackages' property.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"... specify pkg name ...."})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue resolved.

Initially my jsp files was under  `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` and changed to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`.

And This is for war file

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35057123)

Answer (score -1):

If your Spring Boot application utilizes JSP files and static resources, I highly recommend using WAR (Web Archive) packaging rather than JAR (Java Archive) packaging. This is due to the inherent differences in how these two packaging formats handle web application resources.

When you package your application as a JAR file, the "webapp/WEB-INF" folder containing JSP files and other web-specific resources is not included in the packaged JAR. This can lead to issues when running the application as an executable JAR, as the embedded servlet container won't be able to locate these critical resources.

Instead, opt for WAR packaging. This packaging format ensures that the "webapp/WEB-INF" folder, containing your JSP files, static content, and other web resources, is included in the WAR file. This is essential for proper functioning, as the embedded servlet container can access and serve these resources correctly.

To build your application as a WAR package, simply include the following line in your project's pom.xml file:

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGdYq.png)(After this, you can follow the same packaging procedure as you did for JAR packaging)

By making this change, you'll ensure that your WAR package contains all the necessary components for proper web application deployment.

For a more in-depth understanding of these packaging formats and their implications, you can refer to the official Spring Boot documentation:

[Spring Boot - Static Content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

[Spring Boot - Limitations of JSP Support in Jar Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations)